# Show text multi byte in pdf in java itext?

Tags: java, spring, itext, thymeleaf, xmlworker

I have file html :

```
<p>Hello everyone</p>
<p>ユーザロールを持つユーザだけが利用できるコンテンツ</p>
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th> 
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td> 
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td> 
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I using itext to convert to pdf but I can't convert text "ユーザロールを持つユーザだけが利用できるコンテンツ"
This is code java :

```
Document document = new Document();

    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("html.pdf"));
    document.open();
    XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, new FileInputStream(filename), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    document.close();
```

I using itext, xmlworker version : 5.5.3

Comment: Start here : https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/... So the first thing to ask: is that really your exact HTML, or are you omitting that content type information?

Comment: I added "<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>" in file html. When I using browser to open this html so it is ok, it can show text japanese.

Comment: You neither set a font nor a custom font provider. This most likely causes the `XMLWorker` to use the default PDF font which usually is Helvetica with WinAnsiEncoding. Obviously that font cannot be used to display Japanese characters. Furthermore, you use `parseXHtml` without a file encoding. This makes the `XMLWorker` use your program's default encoding, probably set via a define. Whether or not this encoding coincides with the encoding of your HTML file, I cannot tell.